# WPF controls, disable changes to `SelectedItem` when bound property to `ItemsSource` changes

Tags: wpf, data-binding, selecteditem, itemssource

When I use `ComboBox` or other controls that have `ItemsSource` and `SelectedItem` property bindings then each time upon the initial binding during runtime and also each time when the bound collection to `ItemsSource` changes I experience that the content of bound `SelectedItem` object is changed.

How can I disable this?

For example:

I have `<ComboBox MinWidth="300" ItemsSource="{Binding AvailableMasters}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedMaster}">`

When I run the application the `SelectedMaster` property is assigned the first item in `AvailableMasters`. Also, each time the `AvailableMasters` collection changes (for example, by assigning a new collection to the property) the `SelectedMaster` is again adjusted.

The desired behavior is that `SelectedItem` (`SelectedMaster`) is only populated/changed when the end-user clicks with the mouse on that item / chooses that item from the `ComboBox` or other control.

Comment: Did you try a OneWayToSource binding on the SelectedItem property?

Comment: If you want to set once only at starting use binding mode one time only.  Later on selection will change on user selection only.  Are you sure your selected masters do not change on changing available masters?  If that is the case don't raise the property changed event of available masters till not required.

Comment: @Ramankingdom, I am afraid you may have misunderstood. I don't want SelectedItem to ever be affected when the property bound to ItemsSource changes.

Comment: Yes,  then in that case save available master and reset it once source updated

Comment: @Clemens, thank you, this answers the question and it works. Though I decided to mark the answer, Rekshino provided, because it seems the better idea because it works both ways in terms of binding. Sometimes I might want to intentionally reflect a changed `SelectedItem` from the viewmodel in my view. But your suggestion does work in the scope in which I posed my question. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set a flag/bool property before you update the collection and use it in SelectedMaster property. Or do you need only XAML solution?

Comment: This might work as a last resort solution. I use mvvm so I can easily set such flags in the bound properties

Comment: I chose your answer because it allows for more flexibility in terms of two-way binding rather than restricting the binding to `OneWayToSource`.